# What is the most effective way of deploying a pre-release Windows Phone 8.0 App to an end user for test purposes?

Tags: testing, windows-phone-8, agile

Scenario:
I am developing a business App for Windows Phone 8.0 specifically tailored to my customer. 
They are in a differnet country, and non technical.

To support agile development I want to provide them with early version of the App on a regular basis before a proper release/rollout.

I can't find any simple answer on how this is supported.

My customer doesn't have a windows 8 PC, or enterprise sideloading set up (I only know that as a 'thing').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way undoubtedly is beta release. You can add mail ids of your beta testers(this should be the same as the store id that they have signed in on their device with)

Here is more info:-

http://www.risingj.com/archives/351

Comment: Wow.. Why haven't I heard of this before, it doesn't appear anywhere in the "getting started" sections or many of the blog posts I've read. Thank you very much Rajeev, this has lifted a massive weight off my mind.

Comment: Found related how to here http://www.jeffblankenburg.com/2011/11/12/31-days-of-mango-day-12-beta-distribution/ .. And MS Official guide here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/help/jj215598(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: You are welcome Gilesey. The best approach I find is to keep 2 apps for each app on the marketplace, one beta and one public. You can upgrade your beta app first, let the testers evaluate that and then push that to the public release!